# Share popup still uses old Google+ branding

Tags: feature-request, design, sharing

This is what the share icons look like for a post:

[image]

The Google + share button is not using the current Google + logo. Can this be updated?

Perhaps these is relevant:

- [Google + Share guide](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)
- Icon/button: [image]

Comment: Related [Remove Google+ recommendations and references](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316878/312043)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the issue can no longer be reproduced after the clean-up.