# Remove Google+ recommendations and references

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sharing

Now that Google [is officially killing Google+](https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/project-strobe/), we should drop it from the list of sharing suggestions at the bottom of every unanswered question throughout the network (except meta sites). The bandwidth saved will probably outpace the total bandwidth used by Google+.

> [image]

If we do that, let's also remove the older style icon from the "share" popup functionality:

> [image]

And the sharing box on the right sidebar of beta sites like [EOS.IO](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/):

> [image]

And places like the wiki description for meta site tags like [sharing](/questions/tagged/sharing):

> [image]

Comment: Well, looks like someone beat me to editing the tag info.

Comment: I wonder how many times that was ever used.

Comment: @SomethingBadHappened Over/under in Vegas is hovering around 6.5.

Comment: Don't forget the link that's in the "share" popup on every post. ;P

Comment: And the beta site right sidebars.

Comment: I think this was done a while back... not sure when... but if you see any hiding that we missed, let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the Google+ references are removed from all the places.
Please find the screenshots for references.

**In the" Know someone" notice:**

> [image: Know someone]

**Share popup functionality:**

> [image: Share]

**Sharing box on the right sidebar of beta sites like [EOS.IO](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/):**

> [image: Beta sites]

**In tag wiki description:**

> [image: tag wiki]